# Form instance members and static member

Tags: c#

I have a formdlg which can be accessed from two 2 forms 
For button click on Form1, it needs to be instance- can have multiple formdlg

But from the other place, I would need only a single instance of formdlg

Any ideas
Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is an example code of the class which can provide the answer for you.

```
class formdlg
{
    static formdlg instance;
    public static formdlg GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new formdlg();

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Since the constructor is public you can call new in the Form1 to get multiple instances anytime you want.

In form2 use the static function GetInstance to retreive the single instance everytime.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

Using [Singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

```
using System;

public class myForm : Form
{
   private static myForm Current;

   private myForm() {}

   public static myForm Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (Current == null)
         {
            Current = new myForm();
         }
         return Current;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the base class of `myForm`?

Comment: It's not clear if he really needs a Singleton. To me it seems that he's talking of the same kind of form (formdlg) for both the buttons.